# Does infinite descent require axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, self-learning, natural-numbers

From [Cut The Knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/WhatIs/WhatIsInfiniteDescent.shtml):

> Let $P$ be a property that integers may or may not possess. If an assumption that a positive integer $n_0$ has property $P$ leads to the existence of a smaller positive integer $n_1<n_0$ that also satisfies $P$, then no positive integer has that property.

I intuitively get that we can show by contradiction that if $P$ holds for some natural number, then we get a sequence of infinite descent, which does not exist. But I’m not able to show the existence of such a sequence from assuming the contrary.

I also have a feeling that this would require AC since this (might?) involve *choosing* from a lot of possible sequences since there is no particular choice function I can think of from $P$.

---

I’d appreciate if you restrict only to natural numbers even though the above involves integers (so no subtraction is allowed).

Comment: @zarathustra +1. Thanks! That’s it! I just need to formalise it now.

Comment: Too bad I can’t accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: I've added some details and posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One does not need AC to prove the existence of an infinite descending sequence, as there is a way to canonically choose the next element in the sequence. For example taking $n_{k+1}$ to be the greatest integer below $n_k$ satisfying $P$.

Technically, the function $f\colon n_k\mapsto n_{k+1}$ is definable in ZF, and then one can apply the recursion theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem) to get that the sequence $(n_0,n_1,\dots)$ exists.